# How to tune search argument in WP_Query to show only exactly the same results?

Tags: query

Right now I am using this:

```
$args_search = array( 
    's' => $search,
    'post_type' => array( 'post' )
);

$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args_search );
```

But the problem is that it shows everything.

E.g. if `$search` is just `"2386"` and I have in my db 3 posts:

`"12386111"`
`"23861111"`
`"11112386"`

I will get 3 results.

But I want to get 0 results. because it's not a full match.

Only if the search is `23861111` then I need to get the 1 result 23861111.

Or when it is `11112386` I need to type the full `11112386` as a $search variable and not only 2386 or 238 to get the result `11112386`

How to change my query to get the results as I want instead of everything that contains the search string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$args_search = array( 
    's' => $search,
    'exact' => 1,
    'post_type' => array( 'post' )
);
```

There is no docs in Codex for 'exact' param, but best (sure the most reliable) docs is the code itself. See the [line 2200 of query.php](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/query.php#L2200)

A limitation: if you have spaces on the search argument it will not work, because `WP_Query` consider search term with spaces as different search terms.

So maybe you can use:

```
$args_search = array( 
    's' => $search,
    'post_type' => array( 'post' )
);
// if no spaces in search we put exact argument
if ( count(explode(' ', $search)) == 1 ) $args_search['exact'] = 1;
```

A note on your code. Right `'post_type' => array( 'post' )` not 'posts' (plural) as you posted.

Comment: Could you send my any link to the WP docs where I can find more about  `'exact'` parameter?

Comment: There is no docs for it. But the best docs is the code itself. See [line 2200 of query.php](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/query.php#L2200) @Derfder

Comment: @Derfder edited the answer to add link.